# Call to a member function bind_result() on a non-object in ... on line 17

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, boolean

I have a books database, using mysqli and prepared statements I am SELECTing all the fields in the DB bar 1.  The reason for this is the error

Call to a member function bind_result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\registersite\phpscripts1\mysqli11.php on line 17

If I miss that field out I do not have any problems, as soon as I add it I get the error.

The database itself is fairly simple, a total of 13 fields, the PK being the id.  The majority of the fields are varchar.

1. [png screenshot of DBase](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3833032/boolError/dbasescheme.png)
2. [Database file link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3833032/boolError/books.sql)

The database field causing the problem is a field 12, condition.  It is set as a varchar(10) but as soon as I introduce it to the SELECT statement it throws a spanner in the works throwing the error above.

I would be grateful if someone could advise why the other fields are working fine yet this one just causes problems.

---

Here is the relevant section of code. Line 17 is the `bind_result` call.

```
include 'connectvariables2.php';
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME) or die("error");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, subject,section,topic,subtopic,title,publisher,authors,isbn13,isbn10,cdincluded,condition,notes FROM books ORDER BY id ASC");

var_dump($stmt);

$stmt->bind_result($id,$subject,$section,$topic,$subtopic,$title,$publisher,$authors,$isbn13,$isbn10,$cd,$cond,$notes);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: In case anyone needs it here is another link 3. [View Source prior to error](http://pastebin.com/UZnsM3mh)

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: [My Code](http://pastebin.com/ybxUexEn) - I have had to make links to pastebin as it would not let me paste in here, says was too long.

Comment: @BaffledBeyondBelief Please post your entire query chunk on this text. This error usually refers to the query being input wrong. Check that the referenced tables, columns exist... and if your selecting a certain row, ensure that the data you are referencing exists.

Comment: @BaffledBeyondBelief Just to clarify, your query chunk on lines 13 - 20 for example.

Comment: @Daryl Gill - The query works with every field bar 1 which is field 12, titled condition, I have the script working until I include it.  I then get the error when I have it in the SELECT statement

Comment: @BaffledBeyondBelief Then post relivant code into your question, your debugging process should narrow it down to the line(s) throwing this error. If you haven't narrowed it down, I suggest you start your debugging process then update your question with your findings

Comment: Query $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, subject,section,topic,subtopic,title,publisher,authors,isbn13,isbn10,cdincluded,condition,notes FROM books ORDER BY id ASC");

Comment: Update your question with your entire query execution. Not post in the comments, by query execution I mean the following: `$stmt->prepare();`, `$stmt->execute();`, `$stmt->bind_result();`, `$stmt->fetch();`

Comment: Debugging, I have no problems in the script until I add this one field.  When I add the field throwing the error The var_dump tells me nothing.  I have never come across a varchar coming up with an error that is saying it is a bool, this makes no sense.  I will keep trying to work it out but thought someone may have come across this problem.

Comment: `code`$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, subject,section,topic,subtopic,title,publisher,authors,isbn13,isbn10,cdincluded,condition,notes FROM books ORDER BY id ASC");
 
 
 var_dump($stmt);
 
 $stmt->bind_result($id,$subject,$section,$topic,$subtopic,$title,$publisher,$authors,$isbn13,$isbn10,$cd,$cond,$notes);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();`code`

Comment: @BaffledBeyondBelief Whats the difference between the working set, and the non working set? whats changed? Whats your expected output, what output are you getting.. All of this needs to be in your question detail.. and As I said.. press the "edit" on your question, add the lines of code you have just commented into the question with the proper formatting.

Comment: the only difference is me adding 1 field to the select statement, then that same field as a variable to the bind_result then echoing it out.  The problem is it won't even get passed when I enter it into the SELECT statement.  This is where the error is coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONDITION` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql, so you need to escape it using backicks:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, subject,section,topic,subtopic,title,publisher,authors,isbn13,isbn10,
                        cdincluded,`condition`,notes FROM books ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Comment: Jeroen, thanks a lot, I forgot about reserved words and checking.  That solved the issue, everything working now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, subject,section,topic,subtopic,title,publisher,authors,isbn13,isbn10,cdincluded,‌​condition,notes FROM books ORDER BY id ASC"); var_dump($stmt);

$stmt->bind_result($id,$subject,$section,$topic,$subtopic,$title,$publisher,$au‌thors,$isbn13,$isbn10,$cd,$cond,$notes);

 $stmt->execute(); 

$stmt->store_result();
```

The above is your current code which you have provided.. You are performing the correct steps to retrieve data from your database, but ordering your execution process wrong. You should read up the on the documents for how to correctly bind a result and store the results.. Here is what your execution process should look like:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result();
$stmt->fetch();
```

But you are trying to store the result, so replace `$stmt->fetch()` with

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

[Stmt::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[stmt::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

[stmt::bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

[stmt::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

[stmt::store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)

---

Regarding your query when adding another referenced column.. *condition* is a reserved key word in mysql.. You need to escape it, so your query will be:

```
SELECT id, subject,section,topic,subtopic,title,publisher,authors,isbn13,isbn10,
                        cdincluded,`condition`,notes FROM books ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: @jeroen I don't know what your on about ;) +1 for pointing out the reserved word

Comment: Ok so followed your advice regarding fetch and store, saved reloaded and the the error is now pointing towards the $stmt->execute(); with bool(false) 
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\registersite\phpscripts1\mysqli12.php on line 16

Comment: @BaffledBeyondBelief Bit stupid question to ask.. But I should, did you add your edited query into the `$stmt->prepare();` ? non-object usually refers to a non-existant reference

Comment: @BaffledBeyondBelief If your code worked before, it should work with the added field as well as soon as you escape that field.

Comment: @BaffledBeyondBelief A nice little debugging line would be to add: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` at the top of your script.. This will give an exact error message

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. And reason was that my table doesn't contains column name which I specified in `prepareQuery` method.